# How to get google app engine admin mail address?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

Is there a way in Google App Engine (Java) to **get the the email address of the admin** that is allowed to send mails **without hardcoding it somewhere**?

Currently I use the Java System property in the appengine-web.xml. Something like the uploader of the app would be fine, too.

Background of this question: I create an app that students have to clone in their own GAE instance. Hence the cloning effort should be minimized as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the way to figure out the email id that is valid to send out mail from. You can figure out the appid dynamically using the App Identity API and construct the sender email id dynamically.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/

Once you have the appid you can construct the email id  as  string@appid.appspotmail.com where 'string' can be anything and 'appid' is the appid you got from the Identity API.

Comment: Thanks for the anser. I use now the following one-liner: `msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("admin@" + SystemProperty.applicationId.get() + ".appspotmail.com"));` which results in _admin@<appid>.appspotmail.com_. Using `ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAppId()` results in _admin@e~<appid>.appspotmail.com_, but I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the sending e-mail address seems to have changed (as of 2016) and so I would use:

```
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(SystemProperty.applicationId.get() + "@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"));
```